# Is there a way to upload images to server/folder using flutter web?

Tags: php, dart, flutter-web

Is there a way to upload images to a folder using flutter web. All examples I am seeing are using flutter app or mobile. I am getting all kinds of error from
Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace.
to:
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'readAsBytesSync'
method not found
Receiver: "blob:http://localhost:56058/83544616-abe2-4f5c-ac7b-a15a52e4d2e1"
Arguments: []

I have been using this flutter function with image picker and  a php backend.

```
 Future _uploadimages() async {
     var apiUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.redhowler.com/web/db/upload.php");
     String bytes = base64Encode(_image.readAsBytesSync());
     

    Map mappedData = {
      'name': fileName,
      'image': bytes
    };
     
    http.Response response = await http.post(apiUrl, body: mappedData);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);
  }
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65579996/1772933

Comment: John Tyner. It only explains how to pick an image and display it on flutter web. It doesn't explain nothing about backend interaction to upload it to a folder.