# How to save Flutter web file_picker selections to host directory

Tags: flutter, dart

There are numerous examples online for using `file_picker` and uploading to Firestore, SQL etc; but it appears there are none for uploading right to the webhost directory where index.html is being served (i.e `./uploads`).

As I am using flutter web in a corporate environment my options for spinning up remote storage options are nearly nil.  I merely want my flutter web app to allow users to upload to our own environment (*I host my web build off Sharepoint and it works perfect*).

The solution for posting to web found here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759028/82856) is very close to what I need except for the `http.MultipartRequest` part as I don't have a server API listening for POST requests.  What other options do I have for merely writing uploads to a directory like ./upload? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, I am searching for the same solution since days... Did you find a solution and maybe can you share it? :)